# Inhabilitar botón después de ser pulsado

Tags: javascript-objeto

Estoy requiriendo una función javascript que al pulsar en un botón este quede des-habilitado explico.
Botón #1 pulso en el y este queda des-habilitado.
Botón #2 pulso en el y este queda des-habilitado y el botón #1 se vuelve a habilitar.
La situación es que son 20 botones por lo menos y no doy con el código.
Hago mención que el botón es una imagen agrego código

```
a href="#top" onClick="carga01()"><img src="../jpg/koryo.jpg">
</a>
```

Agradeceré cualquier respuesta a este mensaje.

Comment: Que has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que se presiona un boton a la vez, esto habilita el boton deshabilitado cuando uno nuevo es presionado y deshabilita el presionado. Está con tres botones pero puedes poner todos los que quieras. La funcion disabled en true deshabilita y en false habilita.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click en el boton para deshabilitarlo y habilitar el anterior</p>

<button onclick="myFunction(this)">Try it 1</button>

<button onclick="myFunction(this)">Try it 1</button>

<button onclick="myFunction(this)">Try it 1</button> 
<script>
var a = "";
function myFunction(e) {
 a.disabled=false;
 a=e}
 e.disabled=true;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Cuando se trata de enlaces la logica es similar, cuando hace click valida que no sean repetido, osea que no sea el mismo boton, y si lo es no hace nada, una forma para deshabilitarlos es cambiando el href, así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href = "https://www.google.com" 
target="_blank" 
onclick="myFunction(this)"><img 
src="../jpg/koryo.jpg">
</a>
<a href = "https://www.google.com" 
target="_blank" 
onclick="myFunction(this)"><img 
src="../jpg/koryo.jpg">
</a>
<a href = "https://www.google.com" 
target="_blank" 
onclick="myFunction(this)"><img 
src="../jpg/koryo.jpg">
</a>

<script>
var a = "";
var aHref = "";
function myFunction(e) {
 if (a==e) {
  a.href="javascript: void(0)";
  a.target="_self";
} 
else {
 a.href=aHref;
 a.target="_blank";
 a=e;
 aHref=e.href;
}

}
</script>
</body>
```

Para la pagina que dejaste extraje parte del codigo para probar y lo solucionaría así, solo validando que no se repita el mismo boton para actualizar el video principal . El elemento video tiene un atributo onended cuando termina de reproducir puedes hacer el llamado a una funcion si quieres volver a usar el boton.

```
<html>
</body>

<video id="myVideo"  controls onended="myFunction()" autoplay poster="http://enviasiete.com/tae2020/jpg/fuente.jpg">
       <source id="mp4_src" src="http://enviasiete.com/tae2020/videos/intro.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
   Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
   </video>
            <p class="separacionVideos"></p>  
    
   <!--  VIDEOS MOBIL   -->  
    
     <div id="videosMobil">   
    <a href="#marcaVideo" onClick="carga01(this)"><img  src="http://enviasiete.com/tae2020/jpg/koryo.jpg">
</a>        
        <p class="separacionVideos"></p>  
    
    <a href="#marcaVideo" onClick="carga02(this)"><img src="http://enviasiete.com/tae2020/jpg/kumgang.jpg">
</a> 
</div>

<script> 
var a=""

function myFunction() {
 if (a!="") {
   a.style.opacity=1;
   a="";
 }
}

function carga01(e) {
if (a!=e) {
   if (a!="") a.style.opacity=1;
   a=e;
e.style.opacity=0.5;


document.getElementById("mp4_src").src = "http://enviasiete.com/tae2020/videos/koryo.mp4";  

document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
}

}

function carga02(e) { 
if (a!=e) {
  if (a!="") a.style.opacity=1;
  a=e;
  e.style.opacity=0.5;


document.getElementById("mp4_src").src = "http://enviasiete.com/tae2020/videos//kumgang.mp4";  

document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
} 
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: estimado Angel te comento tu código es bueno de hecho esta probado, el problema radica en que  no logro ponerlo en la imagen que hace las veces de botón.

Comment: Agradezco nuevamente tus finas atenciones,estoy por probar el código que me envías,en breve lo comento..

Comment: No me corre el código ademas de abrir en otra pagina,(necesito abra en la misma. te proporciono el link a la pagina para ejemplo visual http://enviasiete.com/tae2020/html/videos.html

Comment: @Erik, si te refieres a los videos probé solo haciendo que no haga nada cuando es el mismo boton pulsado para que no actualice el video en cuestion.

Comment: Estimado Angel si fueras tan amable de publicar en que forma colocaste el código porque a mi no me corre. Gracias por tus finas atenciones y quedo pendiente..

Comment: Una disculpa encontré el código a que me refería ya lo habías puesto,gracias nuevamente y en breve comento...

Comment: Mil gracias,definitivamente cumple con mi requerimiento,quedo a tus ordenes para posteriores encuentros,hasta entonces..

Comment: Realice los cambios en el servidor y lo dicho, corre de maravilla,abusando de tus conocimientos por ultimo, seria genial que el botón inactivo se atenuara, es decir, bajara su luminosidad con respecto a los otros....Como siempre agradezco tus finas atenciones..

Comment: Ahi puedes cambiar la opacidad con css al momento en que validas que no se repita el boton, el parametro de .style.opacity va de 0 a 1.

Comment: <a href="#marcaVideo" style="opacity: .5" onClick="carga01(this)"><img  src="../jpg/koryo.jpg">
    </a>     definitivamente el css no va en ese lugar porque desde un principio carga la opacidad,acáso va en el código javaScript?

Comment: Si, va en el script, edité el codigo de la respuesta.

Comment: Agradezco la rapidez en la respuesta y la disponibilidad de compartir tus conocimientos,espero seguir manteniendo contacto contigo,quedo a tus apreciables ordenes,afectivamente Erik Ramón Palma...

Comment: Buen día seria genial el habilitar el botón al concluir el video. Espero haber sido claro. Agradezco cualquier respuesta..